# sneakyjoystick alternatives for non-cocos2d project?

Tags: ios, joystick

I am working on a project that is in need of a good virtual joystick, but cannot be Cocos2d.  sneakyjoystick seems to be the most popular but is pretty intertwined with Cocos2d.  Are there any good virtual joystick projects that are `UIKit` based?  I'd really like to avoid having to 'port' sneakyjoystick to be non-Cocos2d specific.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this class today after having the same question as you: 
[CPJoystick](https://github.com/Wense/CPJoystick)

Feel free to add your own features to it!